# Slide to reveal in AndEngine

Tags: andengine, gestures

I was designing the game in that i want to cover the scene with black layer and i want user to see it when he slide the image. Is there any functionality in AndEngine for something like slide to unlock.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a very few GUI elements in AndEngine. You will have to implement it yourself. Take a look at `SurfaceGestureDetector` for the slide gesture.